# How to Change a single Array into array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I have below kind of array;

```js
let products = ['playstation',3,'laptop',2,'Television',1,'Mobile',5];
```

I want my above array to be like:

```js
newArray = [{
    product: playstation,
    quantiy: 3
  },
  {
    product: laptop,
    quantity: 2
  } {
    product: Television,
    quanity: 1
  },
  {
    product: Mobile,
    quanity: 5
  },
]
```

Comment: Can you please state, what have you tried so far? and where you are facing trouble??

Comment: Try this:
`products.map((n, i, arr) => ({ product: n, quantiy: arr[i + 1] })).filter((n, i) => i % 2 === 0);`

Comment: @FaridVatani thanks a lot. It's what I really want.